# How do I re-train an existing K-Means clustering model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, pre-trained-model

I have built a k-means clustering model using Sci-Kit Learn. I need to re-train the existing model daily, using new data.

I looked for any technique which can be used to re-train the existing model, but I couldn't find any straight forward method for this.

As I am getting large datasets daily, I cannot re-train the model from the beginning since it is not practical for the long run. Therefore, I need a method that can be used to re-train the existing model using new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have a look at **Online Learning** techniques for that. Many [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) algorithms have an option to do a `partial_fit` of the data, which means that you can incrementally train on small batches of data.

In your case, you can use [`sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html), which is trained by taking a fraction of the samples (batch) to update the parameters of the model on each iteration, thus making it a natural candidate for online learning problems. However, the model must still be trained through the method `partial_fit`, otherwise it will retrain the whole model.

Answer (score 0):

Not every scikit algorithms provides partial training, this one does not allow you to retrain it.

Maybe there is one work-around for you:

You can use the `fit`method and only apply the new points to existings clusters. As your dataset is quite big, maybe this makes sense in the beginning, for sure the risk is there that the cluster quality goes down, everytime you add new data.

The other option would be to write a manual function for k-means , which checks new points and only filter the nearby points for adjusting or use the minibatch algorithm: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html.

Comment: I need to maintain the cluster quality as well during the re-training. Therefore, I think MiniBatchKmeans will help for me.