# What is the best way to progressively perform KMeans clustering using sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to perform KMeans clustering progressively for a dataset using `sklearn`. It's not obvious to me what the best way to do this is from the documentation.

The top-level `KMeans` class provides a `fit` method.

```py
model = KMeans(n_clusters=20)
model.fit(data)
```

However, I'm not sure if this `fit` method (a) stores the desire intermediate results in my model and (b) is the optimal way to compute these intermediate results.

If I want to compute my clusters progressively, should I just call `model.fit` for each slice of my dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need to do `max_iter = 1` because by default it is 300.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep record of centroids of every iteration in k-means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370344/how-to-keep-record-of-centroids-of-every-iteration-in-k-means)

Comment: Yes, I believe that does. Or in the least, it tells me that `.fit` is appropriately stateful.

Comment: @AlexK Do you think this should remain open? It's slightly different from the proposed dupe in that I'm interested in the intermediates, but rather the ability to perform progressively.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what you mean by "progressively".  In your post you say that you want to store intermediate results.  Do you mean something different from what's done in the linked answer, where centroids are retrieved from each iteration, allowing you to analyze/evaluate them as needed?

Comment: @AlexK I don't need to analyze. I just need to update the model.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  What kinds of updates?  What will the updates be based on, if not evaluation/analysis of earlier model results?  Are you not able to do what is done in the linked answer and call kmeans again in a loop with whatever updates you are considering?

Comment: Do you mean you'll want to update your model based on additional data?  That would be online/incremental clustering.  Consider [How do I re-train an existing K-Means clustering model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817645).